# android how to see the touch priority of views

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have a popupWindow and it looks the onClick of a view in it not called and some other view takes the touch. 
How can I increase the touch priority of a view?

This is how I implemented the onClick of the view. The view is inside a popupWindow

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "on click called for view");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You cannot increase a priority.
Only thing you can do is move your View in the XML on a "later" position.
Touch Events go backwards through the XML.

Comment: None of the views in the popupWindow is getting the touch. There are a bunch of other views in the app I am afraid some other view is taking the touch. Is there a way to log that which view is getting the touch?

Comment: i think this is not possible...

If you post your Layout, we can eventualy find out where the problem is